# How list of prefix works in prolog

Tags: prolog

I tryed to understand how this code works but i couldn't.

```
prefix(P,L) :- append(P,_,L).
```

I used query like that `prefix(X,[a,b,c,d]).`If you have got a time, can you explain to me how it works?. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`append`](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse24) you can see that

> append(L1,L2,L3) will hold when the list L3 is the result of concatenating the lists L1 and L2 together (concatenating means joining the lists together, end to end)

So what your predicate above says that something is a `prefix` of something, if you can append *anything* (that is the `_`) to the former and obtain the latter.

Makes a lot of sense, doesn't it? Prolog is nice.